# Error monitoring using AzureWebJobsSDK ErrorTrigger Extension not working

Tags: azure, error-handling, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am trying to trigger an email function when more than 2 errors occur over a sliding window duration of 2 minutes. However during testing, the error monitor does not work. For example in the following function

```
private void Deserialize(string info)
{
     try {
           SampleData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleData>(info); 
         }

      catch ( Exception e ) {
            TraceEvent error = new TraceEvent(TraceLevel.Error, "Error detected");
            error.Properties.Add("ErrorInfo", e.Message);
            trace.Trace(error);
}
```

If the string *info* is can not be deserialized, an exception is thrown, and 2 such errors should trigger this function :

```
  private void ErrorMonitor([ErrorTrigger("00:02:00", 2, Throttle = "1:00:00")] TraceFilter filter)
        {
            EmailInfo();
        }
```

However, this does not work. Am I binding the ErrorMonitor to the TraceFilter properly? This is just a sample code and I have more than one function where errors can occur and ErrorMonitor() needs to keep a track of all those.

**UPDATE:** I discovered that ErrorTrigger works perfectly fine. 
The reason ErrorTrigger was not working is because all exceptions were handled within the try-catch block. ErrorTrigger picks up errors from Trace. And any messages on the console that are not errors (displayed in red) are not considered by ErrorTriggers as errors; regardless of how many exceptions occur.

**UPDATE 2:** Bruce's suggestion enables picking up of error messages from Trace even after handling the errors in a try-catch block. TraceWriter has to be passed in the function where errors are expected. Modified code would be:

```
private void Deserialize(string info, TraceWriter trace) { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirement, I tested it and I could work it as expected on my side. Please pay attention that you do not need to wrap you code with `try-catch`. Errors would be collected automatically by the runtime when errors occur. Here is my code snippet, you could refer to it:

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main()
{
    JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Verbose;
    config.UseTimers();
    config.UseCore();
    JobHost host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

**Functions.cs**

```
public static void TimerWorker([TimerTrigger("00:00:10")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    //Simulate throwing errors when running your logic code
    throw new Exception(string.Format("GenerateError:{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks));
}

/// <summary>
/// Global error monitor function that will be triggered whenever errors
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filter"></param>
public static void ErrorMonitor([ErrorTrigger("00:00:20", 1, Throttle = "00:00:40")] TraceFilter filter)
{
    //log last 5 detailed errors to the Dashboard 
    string errors = filter.GetDetailedMessage(5);
    Console.WriteLine("ErrorMonitor: " + errors);
}
```

**Note:** Upon the code, `ErrorMonitor` would be triggered whenever 1 error occur within a 20 seconds sliding window (throttled at a maximum of 1 notification per 40 seconds).

Additionally, you could also specify the specific error handlers that would only handle errors for the specific function. You could follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) about ErrorTrigger for a better understanding of it.

Comment: I think removing the try-catch makes sense. However there's something I'm curious about. What kind of errors does the ErrorTrigger pick up?

Comment: Is it possible that since I am handling all exceptions and no errors are printed on the console window, ErrorTrigger is not picking them up?

Comment: Where is the variable named "trace" defined in the `Deserialize` function? I tried to modify my `TimerWorker` function to `TimerWorker([TimerTrigger("00:00:10")] TimerInfo timer,TraceWriter trace)`, then wrap my code with try-catch and deal with the exception as the code you provided. In this way, I could find a message "Error detected" marked as Red in my console window. In my opinion, if you do not capture the exception by yourself, then the runtime would pick the exception up automatically.

Comment: I didnot pass TraceWriter to Deserialize() before. I defined a TraceMonitor elsewhere. That approach didn't work though, and what you suggested works fine. I can see error messages in my console but earlier they werent being detected by the trigger. Works fine now, thanks